# .Net 6 WEB API & ANGULAR : user undifiend

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I have a LOG IN page and as soon as I fill out the form I get to the home page and on the home page I want to display the username by ID.

For example userName = "Lior"

So on the home page I want it to say Hello Lior

HttpClient:

```
GetUser(id: string):Observable<User>{
    return this.http.get<User>(this.baseUrl + this.usersUrl + '/' + id)
  }
```

Login.ts

```
login(){
    this.usersService.GetAllUsers()
    .subscribe(res=> {
        const user = res.find((a:any)=>{
        return a.userName === this.loginForm.value.userName && a.password === this.loginForm.value.password
      });
      if(user){
        alert("Login Success!");
        this.loginForm.reset();
        this.router.navigate(['home']);

  }
```

HomePage.ts:

```
user!: User;

  constructor(private usersService: UsersService,private route:ActivatedRoute) {
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.accountService.GetUser(this.user.id).subscribe(res => {
    //   this.user = res;
    // })
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
      params =>{
        const id = params.get('id');
        if(id){
          this.usersService.GetUser(id)
          .subscribe(
            response =>{
              this.user = response;
            }
          )
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

HomePage.html

```
<div class="p-4">
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Hi {{user?.userName}}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**I get that user untifiend**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not see anywhere that you send the id parameter. you cand send parameters like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['home'], { queryParams: {id: user.id}});
```

and use

```
 this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe()
```

for subscription. Also, subscribe to route in the `constructor()` instead of `ngOnInit()`.

Besides this, there are some problems with your code and your idea to get the user. first, do not use subscribe inside subscribe. for example, you can use `switchMap` here. second, unsubscribe() all your subscriptions to avoid memory/DOM leak.

when you need to keep track of a property (user in this example) in some parts of your application you are facing a term called "state management" you can use a simple service with an rxjs Subject in it or in larger apps using Ngrx or so on.

Comment: I changed the line you told me to change in login and it still does not display the userName

Comment: Could it be because in routing I did not set id?
**{path:'home', component:HomeComponent},**

Comment: move your subscription to route from ngOnInit to constructor. check if your subscription code ever calls.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue, but I get every overhaul of the [object Object] alert page
Because of the url **http: // localhost: 4200 / home / 298a227d-466d-45b9-a0f7-2ed5c7272bf9? Id = 298a227d-466d-45b9-a0f7-2ed5c7272bf9**

Comment: if you changed  `{path:'home', component:HomeComponent}` in the routing module, undo the changes.

Comment: I deleted it
  **{path: 'home /: id', component: HomeComponent},**

But now I do not have the userName either

Comment: This part:
        this.router.navigate ([`home / $ {user.id}`], ([{queryParams: {id: user.id}});])


Makes me get alert of [object Object]

Comment: use `this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe()` and `this.router.navigate(['home'], { queryParams: {id: user.id}});`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wanted to ask if delete and put is on the same principle that if I want each user to have delete and put separately from the others it will be the same job?

And update your code so I can mark V

Comment: please ask a new question for it.

Comment: I will try alone, if I do not succeed I will open a new post thanks.